# Using C# with ArcGISRuntime, how do I use a StretchRenderer to make a grayscale color ramp?

Tags: raster, c#, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

Using C# with ArcGISRuntime I need to display raster data on a map.  Right now I have the following code that successfully displays an elevation raster (DEM) on the map.  However, I have other rasters that are not displayed correctly using this color ramp.  When I bring them into Arc Map, they are displayed the way I want them, as grayscale images.  How can I define a StretchRenderer that would be a grayscale color ramp, that would make these rasters appear the same as they do when bringing them into Arc Map?

```
private void AddRasterLayer(string rasterPath, string id)
{            
    var newRaster = new Raster(rasterPath);            
    var newRasterLayer = new RasterLayer(newRaster);
    newRasterLayer.Id = id;
    // Code to get the min and max values for the MinMaxStretchParameters object
    double[,] rasterArray = Conversions.RasterToArray(rasterPath);
    double max = SoilMoisturePreprocessing.Max2d(rasterArray);
    double[] minVals = { 0 };// 0
    double[] maxVals = { (int)max + 1 };
    MinMaxStretchParameters minMaxParams = new MinMaxStretchParameters(minVals, maxVals);
    ColorRamp elevationColorRamp = ColorRamp.Create(PresetColorRampType.Elevation);
    var rendrr = new StretchRenderer(minMaxParams, null, true, elevationColorRamp);

    newRasterLayer.Renderer = rendrr;
    newRasterLayer.Opacity = 0.6;
    var mapViewModel = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MapViewModel>();
    mapViewModel.Map.OperationalLayers.Add(newRasterLayer);
}
```

Comment: By the way, Max2D and RasterToArray are my own methods that I use to get the max value in the array.